# Getting Error in vba and cannot figure it out

Tags: vba

Trying to get this code to work when hitting a button but im getting this erorr

"A problem occurred while Microsoft Accces was communicating with the OLE server or Acitve X Control."

here is the code

```
enter code here

Private Sub Command36_Click()

Dim months2, years2, countyID2 As Integer
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim SQL

months2 = txtMonths.Value
years2 = txtYears.Value
countyID2 = txtCountyID.Value

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)


DoCmd.RunSQL "select * from Rule where ChangedFlag = 1 and Years = " +         years2 + " and Months = " + months2 + " and CountyID = " + countyID2 + ""

If IsNull(rs) Then MsgBox "Hearing dates are already assigned! Please choose   another county, year, or month!"
Else
DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into Rule values (Years, Months, CountyID) Values  (years2, months2, countyID2)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: It does not say. When you click the button i get the error.

Comment: GD Jordan, what Om3r is referring to is setting a breakpoint on -for example- on the Private Sub line, that way your code will break once you click the button. Assuming you use MS Access you can then step through the code by using F8, you can see the progression of the execution and watch which statement is executed last, just prior to the error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "select * from Rule where ChangedFlag = 1 and Years = " + _
         years2 + " and Months = " + months2 + " and CountyID = " + countyID2 + ""


DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into Rule values (Years, Months, CountyID) Values " & _
             " (years2, months2, countyID2)"
```

In your second SQL statement you're trying to insert literal values "years2", "months2" and "countyID2".

Compare that with your first statement...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I replaced the insert statement with the second line of code you wrote and im stlll getting the same error.

Comment: this is a detailed explanation of our error

This error occurs when an event has failed to run because the location of the logic for the event cannot be evaluated. For example, if the OnOpen property of a form is set to =[Field], this error occurs because a macro or event name is expected to run when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

GD Jordan,

Your error indicates that you do not get a connection to the database. Which would make sense as you have not indicated where, or to what object, the connection should be made.

In your code you have declared `SQL` and subsequently use it in your `OpenRecordSet(SQL)` statement, yet the variable `SQL` is not defined (i.e. it is declared but does not contain any value or information with which to execute the `OpenRecordSet()` method)

Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx
For more information on the appropriate use of the `OpenRecordSet()` method.

Once you have checked that you indeed get the connection (using debugger in VB editor for example) you can then determine how you want your code to interact with the `rs` object.

By the way there is more wrong with your code, but let's focus on getting the connections first...

Good luck !